# autonum breaks align* and equation*

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, amsmath

The autonum package apparently doesn't like me to declare math modes to be unnumbered, and prefers to do this on its own. Can't really tell if this is intended behavior and if so, why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x &= a+b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of the [autonum package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/autonum) is to automatically number only those equations that you reference in the text. Therefore using unnumbered maths environments alongside autonum does not make sense. Page 1 of the documentation says 'never use the starred form'.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I should have read the manual. I was including some tex files which predated working with `autonum` and they used the starred versions pretty liberally. I didn;t think it would have bothered `autonum`. Thanks for your reply. My bad.

Comment: @FgNu, Ian Thompson is completely correct with his reasoning. When I switched to using autonum myself, I searched for starred math environments and replaced them by their unstarred version in my documents, as I optimized for consistency. I now see, that this reduces compatibility to old documents. Is there interest to have a package option deciding between consistency (starred versions forbidden) and compatibility (starred versions as without autonum)?

Comment: I think that actually should not be a problem. I can just put together a simple python script to go through my files and turn all starred environments into unstarred environments.

Comment: It’s definitely bad design to have `autonum` break starred environments. At the very least, `autonum` should redefine `\begin{align*}` to be `\begin{align}` — the user should not be forced to destructively change their LaTeX before it being compatible with `autonum`.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify autonum.sty to work with align*, equation*, gather*, and \Cref by copying it into the directory of your main latex file and replacing
`\AtBeginDocument{<existing>}`
with

```
\AtBeginDocument{
<existing>
\ifdef{\Cref}{\autonum@generatePatchedReferenceCSL{Cref}}{}
\newenvironment{align*}{\align}{\endalign}
\newenvironment{equation*}{\equation}{\endequation}
\newenvironment{gather*}{\gather}{\endgather}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).